# How to select Radio button in Capybara with adjacent text?

Tags: text, radio-button, capybara

The capybara choose method works well for a radio button which has the label tag next to it with the required text, like below:

```
<input id="rGEQr-real" type="radio" name="_pgcr6g7j"/>
<label id="rGEQr-cnt" class="z-radio-content" for="rGEQr-real">Web IDE Support</label>
```

`page.choose('Web IDE Support')` works fine for this.

But for something like this:

```
<form action="">
<input type="radio" value="male" name="sex"/>
MALE
<br/>
<input type="radio" value="female" name="sex"/>
FEMALE
</form>
```

which doesnt have label tag, the simple `choose` fails to set radio button.

**How can we achieve this in Capybara??**

Answer (score 1):

If you need to choose a radio button by anything other than its name, id or label text, you will need to:

1. Find the radio button, typically with `find` and a CSS or XPath.
2. Call the `set` method

In this case, you will need to use XPath since CSS-selectors do not support locating by text. The XPath will need to check that the following sibling text node is the specified text. This can be done with:

```
# Select MALE
page.find(:xpath, '//input[following-sibling::text()[1][normalize-space(.) = "MALE"]]').set(true)

# Select FEMALE
page.find(:xpath, '//input[following-sibling::text()[1][normalize-space(.) = "FEMALE"]]').set(true)
```